# Bootstrap, but I want my table wider than the viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am newish to web development.
I am using Bootstrap to format my site.  On one page I will have a large table with many columns.
So far I said the table should fill the whole screen, but in reality the table is very wide, I'd want most of the columns to show, and 5 or 6 less important  columns to be seen by scrolling to the right.

If I've used Bootstrap I am forcing the table inside the entire view.  Should I not insert the table inside a Bootstrap column and probably container too?  Or is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to answer if you paste add your code. you will have to add the table inside a container or a column depending on the need. And that has to pretty much solve the problem.

You can add additional styles to the table like this

```
<table style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto">
....
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have my code handy.  The table is in a container and column, but I felt maybe I should remove.  By adding that overflow, I think that will work.  Thank you.